# Visual Studio - Splitting so that Design mode is on top

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, settings, split, asp.net

VS2008 seems to have a new feature that allows one to split a website into the source code and design aspects on the same page.  This feature seems great, however it defaults to having the design part on the bottom half of the screen and the code part on the top half.

Unfortunately, my brain doesn't work this way and it ends up being more of a hassle than to just continue switching back and forth when needed like I've done in the past.

Is there a way to swap them so that the design part is on the top and the code part on the bottom?  Most other tools in VS are drag and droppable, so I can't see why not, but I'm not finding the setting anywhere.  I did a quick google search and found a way to make the split vertical, but thats not what I'm looking for.  I'm just looking for the same horizontal split with the design part on top.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach that may help. If it's a traditional .aspx page (one that has a codebehind), you can open both documents simultaneously. Then right click one in the tab area at the top and select **New Horizontal Tab Group**. You can manipulate it so that the design window is on top of the code window.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I'll take it since it looks like this is the closest possible solution to what I want. Ironically, this is an example of a window configuration changes the vertical alignment of the Objects and Events drop-down-lists (as Matthew Jones mentioned), so maybe there is still hope

Comment: Ya, sorry that's the best I could come up with -- that window is like an anomaly that doesn't fit the design of everything else in Visual Studio.

Comment: So, I went to actually make use of this approach today and its not working as expected.  Apparently, VS is only allowing me to open one instance (read tab) of each file.  Meaning I'm not able to open the same tab in both tab groups, even if I am viewing one in design mode and the other in source mode.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I managed to open a simple HTML page (not .aspx) in two windows (VS2013 Pro):   
1) Solution Explorer ⇒ file context menu ⇒ Open With.. ⇒ HTML (Web Forms) Editor;    
2) Solution Explorer ⇒ file context menu ⇒ View Markup;   
3) right click on the tab label of second ⇒ New Horizontal Group

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if this possible, since I have never seen a window configuration that changes the vertical alignment of the Objects and Events drop-down-lists.

I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Ahh, that sounds like a valid explanation why it was decided to keep the code section on top.  Maybe its because of programs like firebug, but it just doesn't feel natural to me although I can at least attribute the decision to something now.

Still hoping theres a workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem rather strange - in the xaml designer you can split the screen whichever way you want as there is a button to switch the position of the panes.  The options for the html designer only seem to allow a vertical or horizontal split though, there isn't anything in there specifying whether to have code or design at the top, it does seem a little backwards as I imagine most people find it more natural to have the visual designer at the top with the code below.